# Objects in java won't execute in main class

Tags: java, class, object, program-entry-point, execute

I'm kind of a programming noob. Started 2 months ago roughly and have been trying to get better. I just moved onto the object oriented stuff and I'm having a bit of trouble. I wrote this test program but none of it will execute. It doesn't have any errors but in the console it repeats

```
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at userinput.<init>(userinput.java:4)
at DialogueOption.<init>(DialogueOption.java:5)
```

over and over again.
Here are the three classes. Sorry if there are any formatting mistakes.

1st class

```
public class window{

public static void main(String args[]){

    DialogueOption Dialogue1 = new DialogueOption();
    userinput userin = new userinput();

    Dialogue1.responseList();
    userin.FIResponse();

    Dialogue1.dialogueOP();

    while(Dialogue1.badinput = true);
        Dialogue1.responseList();
        userin.FIResponse();
        Dialogue1.dialogueOP();

    }   
}
```

2nd class

```
public class DialogueOption extends window {
int DialogueOp1;
window win = new window();
userinput userin = new userinput();
public boolean badinput;

public void responseList(){
    System.out.println("Get out of bed, you lazy ****.");
    System.out.println("1. **** you, bro. I'm staying in bed.");
    System.out.println("2. Fine, lets go to class.");
    System.out.println("3. Eh?");


}


public void dialogueOP() {

        userin.FIResponse();

        switch(userin.Response){
        case 1:
            System.out.println("**** you then");
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("Good guy");
            break;

        }

        if(userin.Response >= 3){
            System.out.println("Bad input, try again.");
            badinput = true;
        }
    }
}
```

3rd class

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class userinput extends window {
    DialogueOption Dialogue1 = new DialogueOption();
    public int Response;

    public void FIResponse(){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int response = input.nextInt();
    Response = response;

    }
}
```

Comment: I totally forgot about my juvenile Dialogue options, sorry if I offended thee D:

Comment: so it works now, but it's going very slow and taking up a lot of cpu. It says on the 3rd class next to input that there's a resource leak and that the Scanner is never closed. Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Within your `DialogueOption` you are creating a `userinput` which is in turn creating a `DialogueOption` object. This creates a chain which keeps on initializing objects until you eventually get a stackoverflow exception.

You need to change your design so as to avoid this circular dependency.

Another note, replace `while(Dialogue1.badinput = true);` with `while(Dialogue1.badinput == true);` or `while(Dialogue1.badinput);`

Comment: Right, I get it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check this: your `new DialogueOption()` creates a new `userinput userin = new userinput();` which creates a new `DialogueOption Dialogue1 = new DialogueOption();` which creates a new `userinput userin = new userinput();`

This goes on forever until you reach a stackoverflow.

also by definition classes do start uppercase.

Comment: Ahh, that's very helpful. Thanks!